# error on opening mysql workbench on fedora 23

Tags: mysql

I have installed `mysql-workbench` on Fedora 23 Virtual machine (VMware) using the command :

```
yum install mysql-workbench
```

Now when I tried to issue the command `mysql-workbench` from terminal I am getting the error :

```
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libzip.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Also I tried to open same using the mysql icon but when I click on this it does nothing. not sure what I am missing here

Comment: what packages your system find if you search in your repos for  : `yum list mysql-workbench-community` ?

Comment: you need to load the right repo

Comment: ahh, you need to purge and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on this link, there is the same problem :
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75803

Check if you have libzip package installed on your machine.
If not, install it and retry.

Comment: I installed both libzip and tinyxml but still no luck. I am still getting the same error message. I had issued this terminal command to install libzip   yum install libzip

Comment: Which error message you get ?